# Input suggestions for react-native app in IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to create an app with a sign up form using `react-native`. Is there a way to possibly get the system's details (like the first name and last name of the phone's owner) as input suggestions once the `TextInput` is onfocus?

I tried using textContentType="givenName" as a property of `TextInput` but it's not working.

```js
<TextInput
    autoCapitalize={'none'}
    autoCorrect={false}
    autoFocus={false}
    defaultValue={null}
    placeholder={'First Name*'}
    returnKeyType={'done'}
    textContentType={"givenName"}
    underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
    value={this.state.fname_val}
/>
```

Comment: you can use this library to get system information: https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info#readme